# New to SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently building a small application, which I intend to connect to a remote MSSQL database some day, and I want to make sure I've understood the logic behind. When I want my application, on the customers machine to retrieve data from the database, I need to built an application which is located on the same machine as the database, which connects and pulls the data from the database and parses it to the remote application? Did it get this right?

Comment: In a way, sure.  If the DB server and client machines are on the same network (behind the same firewall and on trusted connections) then the clients can probably connect directly to the DB server.  If the clients are distributed across the internet (untrusted connections) then as you suggest it is wise to keep the DB server behind a firewall and expose the business operations via an intermediary application.  This is often a simple web service which exposes only the operations it needs to and maintains user authentication/authorization from the clients.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Am I supposed just to build an intermediary application to do this, or are there other options?

Answer (score 0):

As David said in comments, it depends.

- For an intranet application, the app would be able to connect directly to the database over the intranet.
- For an application that needs to talk to a database over the internet, you will need what generally gets referred to these days as a "REST API" or "RESTful API", which is really unnecessary jargon in my view. There's a relatively jargon-free description of what that means here: http://www.mashery.com/blog/what-restful-api. It really just means your app can talk to the server via standard HTTP requests and get back data in some format - XML perhaps, but more usually (these days) JSON. And yeah, you'll need to develop a backend app to serve these requests.

Comment: Thanks! Let me see if I get you right. I have to build and backend app to serve the requests from the outside-application. The backend application processes these HTTP request and retrieve the wanted data and parses it back in JSON to the outside-application?

Answer (score 0):

Well your close.  The database can be located anywhere, and you typically don't put anything other than the database server on the host.  You can, but it's something you should not do.

The database server talks over tcp/ip, and your application uses a library called a driver to communicate with the server on your programs behalf. You make calls to the driver in your code, and it handles the communication with the database server.  Once the data comes back, the driver has calls for you to get the data and use it.

It's an oversimplification, but generally, that's how it works.

At a higher level, you architect your application depending on need.  Like @David said in the comments, you need to be concerned about firewalls and protecting the data if your building public facing applications.  Internal applications have a more relaxed set of security requirements when connecting all the pieces together.

Software architecture is a big topic, and not really one for this forum, as this is for specific technology questions.  When you start coding, it's a great place to help you get your code working and research things on your own.

Comment: Thanks, Mike! So the first step would be to create an application which can talk to the database server, and pick a driver to handle that in my code, can you recommend one? Then I need my outside-application to connect to the application which talks to the server, and retrieve the needed data, right? Should I create a new subject when I face challenges with the code, or just reuse this one?

Comment: @Recusiwe Again, a big topic and many ways to implement these things.  Ultimately, you want to create a Web Service, which is the gateway between your application and the database.  Here's a tutorial to get you started with interacting with a database.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html  For development purposes, you can download pretty much any server out there (mysql, sqlserver or Oracle).  Install it on your local PC along with a JDK to get started.  Start small and work your way up.  once you have a database, you can move on to creating web services.

Comment: @Recusiwe As you progress, search StackOverflow for questions before asking a new one.  If you can't find your answer, then start a new topic.